# Gulp task for multiple files

Tags: node.js, gulp

I'm trying to create a gulp task that creates (in this case minifies) a css file for every project css there is.
So for Project A it should combine and minify the following files:

```
global.projecta.css
tool1.projecta.css
tool2.projecta.css
```

It needs a kind of loop or something...? If there is a new Project D, it should build it too. If i need to add something like "projectd" to an array, that would be ok too.

This is the directory structure for the css

```
./global.projecta.css
./global.projectb.css
./global.projectc.css

./addons/tool1.projecta.css
./addons/tool2.projecta.css
./addons/tool1.projectb.css
./addons/tool2.projectb.css
./addons/tool1.projectc.css
./addons/tool2.projectc.css
```

This is the not working task

```
// not working....
gulp.task('css', function() {
    return gulp.src(['global.*.css', 'addons/tool*.css', '!*.min.css'])
      .pipe(concat('build.css'))
      .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
      .pipe(minifycss())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('build/css'));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this, although it requires manually entering an array of your projects.

```
gulp.task('css', function() {
    var projects = ['a','b','c'];
    projects.forEach( function(proj) {
        gulp.src(['global.' + proj + '.css', 'addons/tool*.' + proj + '.css', '!*.min.css'])
        ...
    });
});
```

Comment: had to write forEach but thanks for the simple and working tip

Answer (score 0):

This outputs different files for each global project. For each global.project*.css will output global.project*.min.css:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var css = require('gulp-minify-css');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var glob = require('glob');


gulp.task('css', function() {

    glob('global.\*.css', {}, function (er, files) {

        for(var i = 0, cnt = files.length; i < cnt; i++){
            var fileName = files[i].replace('.css', '');
            gulp.src(['global.\*.css', 'addons/tool\*.css', '!*.min.css'])
              .pipe(concat('build.css'))
              .pipe(rename({basename: fileName, suffix: '.min'}))
              .pipe(css())
              .pipe(gulp.dest('build/css'));
        }
    });


});


gulp.task('default', ['css']);
```

Comment: but that will build only one file build.css containing all css. my question was about one build file per project.